# Displaying the ACORD JAXB Java elements in JSP in Struts2

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

**Scenario:**

I am trying to unmarshall the Acord XML(Insurance standard XML) to Java-Acordform and then trying to map the Acordform object to a one more formbean-Policformbean in order to display the values in the JSP where user can edit the values.Again I have to marshall the Java object values to XML.There is an XSD available for this Acpord XML.Suing XMLSpy I have created XSD from XML.Using XJC I have created the java objects from XSD.
Since Acord being a complex XML and the structure of the generated Java object is not straight forward I have created Policformbean.Using Policformbean , I am tring to display the values in the JSP.

**Issue:**

I am facing few issues while setting the acordform to Policformbean.May I know if using JAXB is the best approach for me to display the XML element values when Acord XML is used?
If anyone has worked on JAXB conversion from Acord XML to Java object values, please guide me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What issues are you running into?

Comment: Is it possible to display the JAXB object values- acordForm directly in JSP with out mapping to Policformbean ??  Since Policformbean is a dupicate form bean of acrodForm.While mapping from acordForm to Policformbean I see difficulty in setting the values since it is being Acord XML and here the JAXB objects are created with  @XmlElementRefs and 
protected List<Object> content; I can email you my code since I am not able to paste the code here.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan - Could you please help me with right direction on this issue.